# How to refer to table cells using (a), (b), (c) and so on?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, enumerate, labels

I have a table with two columns.
The first column is counters of form (a), (b), (c), and so on.
The second column is the content.

I want to refer to each row with labels (a), (b), (c), and so on,
in both table cells and text.

But `\label{cell:a}` (certainly) does not work.
See the [editable code @ overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2775273114hhgnznsksbkx)
and the figure below.

[image: label-table-cell]

How to achieve it?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \label{table:label-in-cell}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  (a) \label{cell:a} & aaa \\ \hline
  (b) \label{cell:b} & bbb (Cell \ref{cell:a} [\textcolor{red}{What I want: Cell (a)}]) \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

  refs to table cells: Cell \label{cell:a} and Cell \label{cell:b}

  \textcolor{red}{What I want: Cell (a) and Cell (b)}
\end{document}
```

dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism is based on `\label` being able to associate its argument with the most recenlty incremented counter variable.

To achieve your formatting objective, then, you need to

1. define a counter variable,
2. define how the counter variable is supposed to be displayed (here: "(a)", "(b)", "(c)" etc rather than "1", "2", "3" etc), and
3. when necessary, increment this counter variable suitably. By "suitably", I mean that one has to use `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter` to perform the incrementing. `\refstepcounter` is required because we need to tell LaTeX *which counter* to use -- *viz.*, the counter most recently incremented via `\refstepcounter` -- when creating the association or link between the argument of `\label` and a counter.
4. If the entire visible content of the left-hand cell is the value of the counter variable, and if the values of the counter are supposed to be consecutive (as is the case in the example code you provided), I'd also recommend creating a dedicated column type that automates the incrementing and displaying of the value of the counter variable.

[image]

A separate comment: Presumably, you also want `cellcounter` to be reset to 0 each time a new `table` environment starts. To achieve this additional objective, you would need to (a) change `\newcounter{cellcounter}` to `\newcounter{cellcounter}[table]`, in order to subordinate the `cellcounter` counter to the `table` counter, (b) use `\caption` directives in each table, as it's the `\caption` directive that actually increments the `table` counter, and (c) place the `\caption` directives before rather than after the `tabular` code block. Aside: Since your sample code contains but a single `table` environment and no `\caption` directives, I didn't implement the preceding instructions in the following code.

```
\documentclass{report}

% Define a new counter:
\newcounter{cellcounter} % feel free to use a different name
% Define how this counter variable should be displayed:
\renewcommand{\thecellcounter}{(\alph{cellcounter})}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
% A column type that automatically increments and displays the counter
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\refstepcounter{cellcounter}%
                    \thecellcounter}c}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  %%\label{table:label-in-cell} % this doesn't have the desired effect
  \begin{tabular}{|Z|c|}
  \hline
  \label{cell:a} & aaa \\ \hline
  \label{cell:b} & Cell \ref{cell:a} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the *header* row (the first row) when automatically incrementing and displaying the counter?

Comment: @hengxin - Sure: Just insert the instruction `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}` in the top left cell.